# Custom Performance Counters in Windows Azure Web Sites

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, performancecounter

I have a Mvc Web Site that I'm deploying via MSDeploy to an Azure **Web Site**.   My web site has a custom [Performance Counter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8f5kw2e(v=vs.110).aspx).

When I deploy the code and run the site from Azure I get an exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.

When calling `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(String categoryName)`.

This makes sense as this call requires elevated permissions (must be a member of the Performance Monitor Users group).

How can I configure my Azure Web Site to correctly create and use Performance Counters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, custom performance counters are not supported in Azure Websites.